# How to calculate ker(A) / null space in R

Tags: r, math

Within some matrix algebra I found the expression `B = ker(A)`, where A is a 3x4 transformation matrix. The following two links gave me some vague idea about ker() in general:

[Wolfram: Kernel](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Kernel.html)

[Calculate the dimensions and basis of the kernel Ker(f)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109003/calculate-the-dimensions-and-basis-of-the-kernel-textkerf)

But frankly, I still can not square how to get a 4x1 vector as result. **How would this kernel be calculated in R?** And some additional background/links would be appreciated.

Here is the matrix A and the result B (or its transpose...).

```
A = structure(c(0.9, 1.1, 1.2, 0.8, 0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 0, 0.2, 
0.7), .Dim = 4:3)

B = structure(c(0.533, 0.452, -0.692, -0.183), .Dim = c(4L, 1L))
```

I did get as far as realizing, that each row of the A-matrix times B equals zero, just like in the examples. But for solving the set of linear equations I am missing one more equation, don't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `pracma` package:

```
pracma::nullspace(t(A))
#            [,1]
# [1,] -0.5330006
# [2,] -0.4516264
# [3,]  0.6916801
# [4,]  0.1830918
```

With the `MASS` package:

```
MASS::Null(A)
```

Comment: Ah, so kernel is null space. That link helps me to find a lot more resources now, thank you.